# Is a closed subsecheme contained in a Cartier divisor?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes, divisors

Let $X$ be a variety over a field $k$. For a closed subscheme $Z\hookrightarrow X$ and a closed point $x\in X$ such that $\text{codim}_XZ \geq 1$ and $x\notin |Z|$, is there an effective Cartier divisor $D$ on $X$ satisfying $|Z| \subset |D|$ and $x\notin |D|$?

When $X$ is an affine variety, I think such a Cartier divisor always exists.

Comment: No, that is not always possible, cf. the example of Hironaka in the appendix of Hartshorne’s textbook.

Comment: take X=the affine nodal curve $\mathbb C[x,y]/xy$, take Z=the node, and take x to be any other point.